# When is an 'identifier' a 'name' in C++?

Tags: c++, c, naming-conventions

When is an 'identifier' called a 'name' in C++? I mostly read that the term `name' is used overly instead of 'identifier' as in the example:

```
struct S { int i };
S thing1;
```

In this case, is the `thing1` a *name* or *identifer*? Or are the terms 'identifier' and 'name' are analogous? In C, is there a use of the term 'name' when referring to an object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C++, the term *identifier* is just a sequence of digits, letters and `_`, not starting with a digit. Such an *identifier* can appear anywhere, and doesn't have to *identify* anything, despite its name (no pun intended).

The term *name* associates a meaning with a certain grammar construct. The C++ spec says that one of the following grammar constructs is a name if it denotes an entity (an *object*, a *class*, a *template* and so on) or a label (where you can jump to with `goto`)

- *identifier*
- *template-id* (`identifier <...>`, `operator-function-id <...>` and `literal-operator-id <...>`, as in `foo <int>`).
- *conversion-function-id* (`operator type`, as in `operator int`)
- *operator-function-id* (`operator @`, as in `operator +`)
- *literal-operator-id* (`operator "" identifier`, as in `operator "" _foo`)

For each of these constructs, the rule when a name is the same as another name is defined differently: For identifiers, two names are the same of the sequence is the same (this is only a lexical comparison). For names of form *conversion-function-id* they are the same if the type used is the same type (so this is a semantic comparison).

As you can see in the example of *literal-operator-id*, the non-terminal *identifier* can appear in the grammar in places where it is not a name. So not every *identifier* is a name, and not every name is an *identifier*. In the example of *template-id*, we have a nested use of names. The constructs before the `<...>` respectively are names again, as they denote declared templates.

Comment: Very succinct and the most accurate description of the distinction.