# User-defined literals, underscores, and global names

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11, we get user-defined literals. The C++ standard has examples of these, such as:

```
long double operator "" _w(long double);
```

And it says the literal should start with an underscore:

> **17.6.4.3.5 User-deﬁned literal suﬃxes**
>   Literal suﬃx identiﬁers that do not start with an underscore are reserved for future standardization.

However, there's another section in the standard that says

> **17.6.4.3.2 Global names**
>   Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>   — Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
>   — Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

I'm looking to better understand exactly what 17.6.4.3.2 (Global names) says/means and how it relates to 17.6.4.3.5 (User-deﬁned literal suﬃxes). Specifically:

- Does the second part of 17.6.4.3.2 (Global names) require user-defined literals (like the above `_w`) to be defined in a namespace (that is, not in the global namespace)? If so, I wish the standard would've illustrated this.
- I presume that the first part of 17.6.4.3.2 (Global names) rules out user-defined literals like `_W` (followed by upper case) and `__w` and `_w__` (two consecutive underscores). Correct?

---

**Edit:**

As a follow up, there's a part of the standard that says:

> **13.5.8 User-deﬁned literals**
>   [...]
>   2 *A declaration whose declarator-id is a literal-operator-id shall be a declaration of a namespace-scope function or function template (it could be a friend function (11.3))*, an explicit instantiation or specialization of a function template, or a using-declaration (7.3.3). A function declared with a literal-operator-id is a literal operator. A function template declared with a literal-operator-id is a literal operator template.

Emphasis mine. When it says "namespace-scope" does that mean user-defined literals need to be declared in a user-defined namespace (i.e. not in the global namespace)?

**Later edit:**

It did not exist when the question was first asked, but now there is also [this related question and answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13793996/1275653) which readers can additionally check after reviewing the answers below.

Comment: Ha, interesting! That looks like an oversight, if you ask me.

Comment: A literal suffix is not a name. According to that interpretation, 17.6.4.3.2 does not apply to 17.6.4.3.5.

Comment: [Consider this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/7f5b4e04f0b01ce5de89a3456db854cb). It does still get mangled by the pp, which can apply to `_<capital>` and `__`, but a global variable of the same name (e.g. declaring `_i` and making a suffix `_i`) does not conflict, so there's no problem with the global scope part of the second rule interfering with your suffixes.

Comment: @chris: Except that the preprocessor is rather blindly replacing the token there; it's not an indication that it is a name at all. This is akin to the way the preprocessor can replace keywords which aren't names. It also shouldn't affect the suffix when actually used as a suffix.

Comment: From 3.3.6 Namespace scope [basic.scope.namespace]: "3 The outermost declarative region of a translation unit is also a namespace, called the global namespace. A name declared in the global namespace has global namespace scope (also called global scope). [...]"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's in a name? 3 Basic concepts [basic] tells us:

> 4 A name is a use of an identifier (2.11), operator-function-id (13.5), literal-operator-id (13.5.8), conversion-function-id (12.3.2), or template-id (14.2) that denotes an entity or label (6.6.4, 6.1).

which we cross-reference with 13.5.8 User-defined literals [over.literal]:

> *literal-operator-id*:
>    `operator ""` identifier

While the name of a literal operator involves an identifier, that identifier does not denote an entity. (Or it's a different identifier and different name that denotes another entity or label altogether.) As such the name of a literal operator never starts with an underscore.

Something like `operator""__w` *is* problematic but this is not new: `int i__0;` is reserved as well.

Comment: So the distinction is between *name* and *identifier*? *Names* in global namespace starting with underscore are reserved, but not identifiers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's cleverer than that (made me do a triple take). The identifier must denote something, and then it's a name (with applicable restrictions). If you just declare `operator"" _w` (i.e. there isn't an `int _w;` in the same scope or whatever), then `_w` is an identifier in `operator"" _w`, but doesn't denote anything on its own (`_w` alone is invalid) so it's not a name.

Comment: Well 17.6.4.3.5 explicitly calls that bit the “literal suﬃx identiﬁer”. I’m aware that it cannot be *used* on its own but it’s still a defined entity in the standard.

Comment: 2.11 Identifiers [lex.name] is where 'identifier' is defined and is strictly a grammatical construct.

Comment: Since function signatures are also mentioned in the restrictions I suppose that I should mention that those are defined in 1.3.17 [defns.signature] signature and, to the best of my understanding, have no effect on my argumentation.

Comment: So the argument is that a literal-operator-id must denote an entity in order to be a name, but that a literal-operator-id never denotes an entity, so is never a name? If so, it doesn't belong in this list at all.

Comment: @PeteBecker A literal-operator-id is a name. The identifier part of it is not.

Comment: @LucDanton: Isn't the literal `_W` (capital) also problematic because it becomes a potential conflict for implementation defined macros? Because when you declare it, there must be a space between the quotes and the identifier (i.e. `"" _W`), and so `_W` is fair game for a replacement by the preprocessor. Correct?

Comment: @Cornstalks I can't find anything to fault that reasoning.

Comment: So to sum it up, his name starts with `o` and not with `_` :) +1 indeed

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947925/when-is-an-identifier-a-name-in-c