# Underscores, names and literal operators

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

My question regarding underscores in names is partly answered [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12721584/1275653) but either the answer is incomplete or I do not fully understand it.

Sect. 2.14.8.7 of the C++11 standard declares this *literal operator* as an example:

```
long double operator "" _w(long double);
```

Besides declaring the operator, the standard and its example do two further things that, if viewed separately, each make sense:

- it begins the name `_w` with an underscore; and
- it puts the operator in the global namespace.

My question has two parts:

1. According to [the answer linked above,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12721584/1275653) the name `_w` is not an *identifier,* or the identifier `_w` is not a *name,* or ... well, I'm confused.
2. If `_w` is okay, then is the capitalized `_W` okay, too -- as in `60.0_W`, meaning *60.0 watts?*  Or is the preprocessor likely to mishandle the capitalized version?

Undoubtedly like you, I am not in the habit of starting global names with underscores, a habit the standard's sect. 17.6.4.3.2.1 explicitly seems to deprecate.  Therefore, if you can cast some additional light on the matter of underscores, names and literal operators, the light would be appreciated.

Comment: `_W` will cause trouble, as a `#define _W /*anything*/` before the definition of the literal operator will cause the `_W` to be replaced. It's not that the `_W` in `operator"" _W` is reserved, but the implementation may well have a macro `_W` like above. Now, one might wonder if macro replacement on literal-operator identifiers is actually allowed by the standard, and I'd say yes, since the `_W` is a seperate preprocessor token.

Comment: @Xeo:  Thank you.  Do you happen to know where in the standard it is explained that `_W` will cause trouble, please?  If so, I should like to read that section.

Comment: It's mostly subclauses 2.2 and 2.5 for the preprocessing stages / tokens. `_W` is an *identifier*, as such it's a *preprocessing-token*, which, if it names a macro, gets expanded in phase 4.

Comment: @Xeo:  If you made your helpful comments an *answer,* of course I would upvote it (if your reputation is not already so high that you don't care about that).

Comment: I'm not totally sure, although both Clang and GCC confirm my guess. The problem with compilers is that they may have bugs. :) I'll recheck with the Clang devs and consult the standard again and maybe post an answer after that.

Comment: The _W in `operator"" _W` is certainly an `identifier` and as such could be redefined as a macro without warning. That won't affect the `_W` in `27_W` (which is not a preprocessing token), but I think that's cold comfort if the `operator""` can't be defined. 13.5.8 (8) shows that it's not legal to define `operator ""_W` (without the space), because _W is not an identifier in that context. On the other hand, that last construct is, afaics, not usable in a well-formed program, which would make it feasible to add it to the grammar without affecting any existing correct code. C++1y?

Comment: Johannes Schaub - litb suggests in the comments on that answer that the *name* includes the full `operator ""` part (he says "So to sum it up, his name starts with `o` and not with `_`). `_w` is an identifier, while `operator "" _w` is a name. Or at least that's what I got out of my question...

Comment: Also wanted to add that Luc Danton says pretty clearly exactly which part is the name: "A literal-operator-id is a name. The identifier part of it is not." (and from his answer a literal-operator-id is defined as: `operator "" identifier`, where `identifier` is the `_w`). I also asked about `_W` and it seems that this version indeed may be problematic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, I checked back with Richard Smith from the Clang team, and the `_W` part in your literal operator is indeed not a reserved identifier and/or name and it is also a seperate preprocessor token which will get expanded if it names a macro. This is in accordance with the standard subclauses 2.5, where an *identifier* is a *preprocessor-token*, and 2.2 which has macro expansion as part of phase 4, before preprocessor-tokens are replaced with just tokens of the language grammar, which happens in phase 7.

He also mentioned that, [since the Portland meeting of the committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1473), you can say `operator""_W`, which will prevent macro expansion, since the `_W` is not a single identifier anymore. Clang trunk already implements this and compiles the following snippet:

```
#define _W _x

int operator""_W(unsigned long long){ return 42; }

int main(){
  int i = 1337_W;
}
```

Comment: Would this work for _string literals_ as well? Would `"1337"_W` work or does the preprocessor consider it to be two different tokens?

Comment: @K-ballo: Remember, the problem is not with the usage of the literal ooerator for a user-defined literal, it's the declaration where the `_W` is replaced.