# Initialize a constexpr array with user-defined literal

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, list-initialization

Simplified version

```
class C {
 public:
 static constexpr std::array<C, 2> foo {{"1"_C, "2"_C}};
 int x;
 constexpr C(char c) { x=c; }
}
constexpr C operator"" _C(const char * str, size_t n) { return C(*str); }
```

This doesn't fly, because the literals are not understood at the line where the array is defined. But the free literal function can't be moved earlier because then C isn't known.

Is there a solution to this Gordian knot that doesn't involve adding variadic templates or something horrid like that into the code?

Comment: Variadic templates and horrid shouldn't be in the same sentence! :)

Comment: As a side-note, I don't think `_C` is an allowed name, since it's underscore + uppercase letter, which is reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @Xeo: I think `_C` is an identifier and not a name, as talked about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947925/when-is-an-identifier-a-name-in-c), so it is okay. The name would be `operator"" _C`.

Comment: @JesseGood: GCC 4.7  and Clang 3.3 SVN do macro-expansion on the name atleast. :s With `#define _C _x` before the literal operator, if I do `auto x = "hi"_C;`, I get a compiler error, while `"hi"_x` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem doesn't really lie with user-defined literals, but with the fact that `std::array` requires complete types (or really, any `constexpr` initialization does). The following code will also fail to compile:

```
#include <array>

class C {
public:
 static constexpr std::array<C, 2> foo {{C('1'), C('2')}};
 int x;
 constexpr C(char c) : x(c) {} // please use a mem-initializer-list
};
```

With errors similar to (Clang 3.3 SVN here):

```
/usr/include/c++/v1/array:136:16: error: field has incomplete type 'value_type'
      (aka 'C')
    value_type __elems_[_Size > 0 ? _Size : 1];
               ^
t.cpp:5:36: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::array'
      requested here
 static constexpr std::array<C, 2> foo {{C('1'), C('2')}};
                                   ^
t.cpp:3:7: note: definition of 'C' is not complete until the closing '}'
class C {
      ^
```

Comment: Moved the object to a related class. Maybe I should have thunk of it as a design issue all along.